# how I refresh the partial view from Business logic

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asynchronous

View: Index

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"; 
    }

    @section Content1
    { 
        <div>  
         @Ajax.ActionLink("Just refresh", "_Test", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "ContentRefresh", HttpMethod = "Post" }, null) 
        </div>

        @Html.Partial("_Test")
    }

    @section Content2
    { 
        <div id="ContentRefresh">
           @Html.Partial("_Test2")
        </div>
    }
```

View: _Test

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_Test", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "ContentRefresh", HttpMethod = "Post" }, null))
        {  
            @Html.TextBox("Name"); 
            <input type="submit" value="Send name" /> 
        }
```

View: _Test2

```
    @ViewBag.Name:  @ViewBag.DateTime
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult _Test(FormCollection form)
        {
            string name = form["Name"];

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
               Thread thread = new Thread(() => RunThread());
               thread.Start();            

                ViewBag.Name = name == null ? "No one, just refreshing" : name;
                ViewBag.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

                return PartialView("_Test2");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

This event is call from business logic.

```
    public void ChangeEventFromBusinessLogic(object o)
    {
      //event from RunThread....
      //refresch my view
    }
```

the ajax call from the view does work. how I refresh the view from Business logic without any user action.

how I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by implementing HTML 5 feature, WebSocketAPI. This is a push technology, which allows the server to update the client they connected.

`SinglaR` is microsoft implementation of WebSocket for ASP.Net application.

See [`Getting Started with SignalR`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20)

***This will work only in the browser which supports WebsocketAPI***

Comment: @user3008091,You can use ajax and keep ping the server for any update in a perticular interval, if you dont use HTML 5